# Getting part of URI after .htaccess redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm new to .htaccess and I've searched for days but couldn't find solution that fits my situation.

So basically what I want is to use .htaccess redirect requests to a subfolder without showing the subfolder in browser address bar. With following .htaccess file I could achieve it. (note that this is on a local machine instead of the actual webhost)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder/$1
RewriteRule ^(/.*)?$ /subfolder/index.php?rt=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Note that I have "rt=$1" to get routing path information from $_GET[] array. But it looks like the rewrite messed up the URL, which then messed up my router function.

For example, the target UrL for an .ajax function is "index/survey_update", which should result in indexController->survey_update().

But with the redirect, now the path becomes
/subfolder/subfolder/index/survey_update/survey_update.
And the router won't be able to resolve it to the right controller and action anymore.

Can anyone let me know why the URL looks funny (subfolder being duplicated and the last section also getting duplicated), and is there a way to extract the right part of the URL (i.e. index/survey_update in this case) by changing the .htaccess configuration? Thanks.

Comment: If you are using any MVC framework, use their routes functionality. That is much more simpler and most advisable than .htaccess

Answer (score 1):

You can just use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /subfolder/index.php?rt=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Remember that `RewriteCond` is only applicable to next `RewriteRule`.